# Center Align Multiple DIV under single main DIV causing overlapping issue

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to print multiple DIV one after another in single line. Also i need to center the content to the page.
I am able do this with float style but its not Centered to the page. I searched google , it says use display: inline-block; instead of float.

**Here is what i tried, but 2 divs are overlapping.**

```
<div style="text-align:center">   

    <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <a style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;color:#000">
    <div style="display: inline-block;cursor:pointer;position:absolute;margin-left:0px;margin-top:-1px;margin-right:0px;">
    <img src="images/Calendar_blank.png" width="75" height="75">
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;position:absolute;margin-left:0px;margin-top:-1px;margin-right:0px;width:75px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:16px;color:#030">Aug</div>
    <div id="date1" style="display: inline-block;position:absolute; margin-left:0px;margin-top:27px;margin-right:0px;width:75px; "><strong>25</strong></div>
    </a>
     </div>

    <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <a style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;color:#000">
    <div style="display: inline-block;cursor:pointer;position:absolute;margin-left:0px;margin-top:-1px;margin-right:0px;width:75px; ">
    <img src="images/Calendar_blank.png" width="75" height="75">
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;position:absolute;margin-left:0px;margin-top:-1px;margin-right:0px;width:75px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:16px;color:#030">Aug</div>
    <div id="date2" style="display: inline-block;position:absolute; margin-left:0px;margin-top:27px;margin-right:0px;width:75px; "><strong>25</strong></div>
    </a>
     </div>

</div>
```

**Out Put is :**

[image]

> **Expected is :** The Content should be centered to the page & it should not overlap.

**Note:** I dont want to add hardcoded MARGIN to the style. as it will effective while zooming in and out & it will not be page centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is too mired with inline styles for me to debug easily. Below is how you would rebuild your desired layout most basically from scratch.

The key component is adding `display: inline-block` to the light-gray calendar divs to allow them to sit side-by-side: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Values

Also, setting those divs to `position: relative` and their child divs to `position: absolute` allows you to ensure the contained elements' origins are within those parent divs.

Inline styles (styles specified within your HTML) should be kept to an absolute minimum. HTML (markup) is for content primarily. Styles go in your CSS, and behaviors generally belong in JavaScript. This makes your code much easier to read and update (and debug).

A separate CSS file can be linked from your HTML, or it can included in your HTML if wrapped in `<style>` and `</style>` tags.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/lifij/1/

HTML:

```
<body>

  <div id="container">

    <div class="calendar">
      <div class="stripe">
        <h3>Aug</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="number">
        <h1>25</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="calendar">
      <div class="stripe">
        <h3>Aug</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="number">
        <h1>25</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
h1, h3 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.calendar {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.stripe {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```